# Hadoop outputs and pipelined write

Tags: hadoop

A few questions:
1. what is the difference between File_Bytes_Read vs HDfs_bytes_read.
2. When a client is about to write a file hdfs if at the time of passing the first block to first Datanode assuming it is DN1 if DN1 fails will the client still end up writing it or losing it. How does Name node deal at this stage?
Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

I can answer question 1

File_Bytes_Read : is the number of bytes read by local file system. Assume all the map input data comes from HDFS, then in map phase it should be zero. On the other hand, the input file of reducers are data on the reduce-side local disks which are fetched from map-side disks. Therefore, it denotes the total bytes read by reducers.

HDfs_bytes_read: Number of bytes read : denotes the bytes read by mappers from HDFS when the job starts. This data includes not only the content of source file but also metadata about splits.